# Port Java-SE encryption code to BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, cryptography, aes

I have the following encrypt / decrypt routines and need to port them to my BlackBerry project.  Can you please get me started?

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
import java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream;

 public String EncryptData(String data, String skey) throws Exception {      
    String encryptedData = "";        

    try{
       byte [] bData = data.getBytes();
       String alg = "AES/ECB/NoPadding"; 
       SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes(), alg.replaceFirst("/.*", "")); 
       Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(alg);
       cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
       byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(bData);          
       encryptedData = bytesToHex(encoded);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
    return encryptedData;
}



public String DecryptData(String hexString, String skey) throws Exception {

    String decryptedData = "";
    try{
       byte [] bData =  convToBinary(hexString);

       String alg = "AES/ECB/NoPadding";            
       SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes(), alg.replaceFirst("/.*", ""));           
       Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(alg);
       cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
       byte[] decoded = cipher.doFinal(bData);
       decryptedData = new String(decoded);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
    return decryptedData;
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: It looks like you already got started.

Comment: The methods as listed above works perfectly in my Java application.  But does not compile in Blackberry.  I have tried importing the relevant crypto namspaces (net.rim.device.api.crypto.*).  But none seem to match my implementation above.  I need to decrypt data that exist in a file and have to use the same algorithms

Comment: You will need to adapt your code to work with the Blackberry API. It is unlikely that someone will do it for you.  So I would suggest trying it bit by bit and come back with specific questions as to where you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have started.  I actually just need the AES (ECB) class plus the 'how to specify NoPadding'.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest maybe looking through the API documentation for the JDE you are using, in particular I would guess the `net.rim.device.api.crypto` package would probably be of most interest to you.

`net.rim.device.api.crypto.Crypto` might also be a good class to look into since it contains static methods for encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: Agreed - BlackBerry has native APIs for doing AES cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working...

```
byte[] keyData = keyString.getBytes();

    AESKey key = new AESKey(keyData);
    NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream out = new NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream();
    AESEncryptorEngine engine = new AESEncryptorEngine(key);
    BlockEncryptor encryptor = new BlockEncryptor(engine, out);
    encryptor.write(data, 0, data.length);
    int finalLength = out.size();

    byte[] cbytes = new byte[finalLength];
    System.arraycopy(out.getByteArray(), 0, cbytes, 0, finalLength);
    encryptedData = bytesToHex(cbytes);
    return encryptedData;
```